# When I try to get my coronavirus payment on the IRS website, I get an error saying "the information you entered does not match our records"

Tags: irs

I am a US citizen living in Canada.

I went to https://www.irs.gov/coronavirus/get-my-payment, and entered my social security number, my date of birth, my American address and my American zip code

I got the error "the information you entered does not match our records."

I tried to create an IRS account and got the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

I figured it out. The IRS had my Canadian address on file not my American one.